# how to change jdk version in weblogic12c

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, weblogic12c

i have configured weblogic server in eclipse but when ever it starts its taking jdk older version
like
Starting WLS with line:
D:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java -server

i have to change it to higher version.

Comment: On what system(OS) are you working ?

Comment: Update your JDK path in the %DOMAIN_HOME%\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd file and restart your server.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz windows 10

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin i have updated in setDomainenv file as set SUN_JAVA_HOME=D:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

set DEFAULT_SUN_JAVA_HOME=D:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

Comment: @PawełGłowacz windows 10

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin  i have updated in setDomainenv file as set SUN_JAVA_HOME=D:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

set DEFAULT_SUN_JAVA_HOME=D:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_202  but after restarting server its taking as previous version of the jdk like "Starting WLS with line:
D:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java -server

Comment: You may not use the SUN's JVM but Oracle's HotSpot. Read the setDomainEnv.cmd script and update the JAVA_HOME env var when the script sets  JAVA_VENDOR=Oracle

Comment: Check Path Variables/System Variables in your Computer Settings. Check what path to jdk is set first. You should always have the correct one jdk path as first on the list.

Answer (score 0):

On Weblogic 12c you have two different situations:

1) Updating the JDK Location in an Existing Oracle Home

2) Updating the JDK Location in an Existing Domain Home

You could do the following steps:
To update the JDK location in the .globalEnv.properties file:
Use the getProperty.sh|cmd script to display the path of the current JDK from the JAVA_HOME variable. For example:

```
(UNIX) ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin/getProperty.sh JAVA_HOME
(Windows)  ORACLE_HOME\oui\bin\getProperty.cmd JAVA_HOME
echo JAVA_HOME
```

Where JAVA_HOME is the variable in the .globalEnv.properties file that contains the location of the JDK.

Back up the path of the current JDK to another variable such as OLD_JAVA_HOME in the .globalEnv.properties file by entering the following commands:
(UNIX) ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin/setProperty.sh -name OLD_JAVA_HOME -value specify_the_path_of_current_JDK
(Windows) ORACLE_HOME\oui\bin\setProperty.cmd -name OLD_JAVA_HOME -value specify_the_path_of_current_JDK

This command creates a new variable called OLD_JAVA_HOME in the .globalEnv.properties file, with a value that you have specified.
Set the new location of the JDK in the JAVA_HOME variable of the .globalEnv.properties file, by entering the following commands:

```
(UNIX) ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin/setProperty.sh -name JAVA_HOME -value specify_the_location_of_new_JDK
(Windows) ORACLE_HOME\oui\bin\setProperty.cmd -name JAVA_HOME -value
```

specify_the_location_of_new_JDK

After you run this command, the JAVA_HOME variable in the .globalEnv.properties file now contains the path to the new JDK, such as jdk1.8.0_131.

You can read the complete [Oracle Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.3/wlsig/shared-updating-jdk-existing-oracle-home.html)